# Boost asio and array of sockets

Tags: c++, arrays, sockets, boost, shared-ptr

I have to write a program that initializes a array of TCP sockets, and use async i/o to read data using a thread pool. Im new to async io, thread pools, shared_ptrs. What I now have is a working program with **one** socket. Heres the clipping:

```
boost::shared_ptr< asio::ip::tcp::socket > sock1(
    new asio::ip::tcp::socket( *io_service )
);

    boost::shared_ptr< asio::ip::tcp::acceptor > acceptor( new asio::ip::tcp::acceptor( *io_service ) );
    asio::ip::tcp::endpoint endpoint(asio::ip::tcp::v4(), portNum);
    acceptor->open( endpoint.protocol() );
    acceptor->set_option( asio::ip::tcp::acceptor::reuse_address( false ) );
    acceptor->bind( endpoint );
    acceptor->listen();
```

I am stuck in getting **similar code for an "array of sockets"**, that is, I want to have acceptor[], that are binded to endpoint[]. I must pass around pointers to the acceptors an sockets, so shared_ptr comes in, and am unable to get it right.

```
for (i=0; i<10; i++) {
    // init socket[i] with *io_service
    // init endpoint[i]
    // init acceptor[i] with *io_service
    acceptor[i]->listen()
    }
```

(btw, do I really need an socket[] array for this porpose?) Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a full example for using Boost ASIO to implement a TCP echo server listening to multiple ports, with a thread pool to distribute work across multiple cores. It is based on [this](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/echo/async_tcp_echo_server.cpp) example from the Boost documentation (providing a single-threaded TCP echo server).

### Session class

The `session` class represents a single active socket connection with a client. It reads from the socket and then writes the same data into the socket to echo it back to the client. The implementation uses the `async_`... functions provided by Boost ASIO: These functions register a callback at the I/O service that will be triggered when the I/O operation has finished.

`session.h`

```
#pragma once

#include <array>
#include <memory>

#include <boost/asio.hpp>

/**
 * A TCP session opened on the server.
 */
class session : public std::enable_shared_from_this<session> {

  using endpoint_t = boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint;
  using socket_t = boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket;

public:
  session(boost::asio::io_service &service);

  /**
   * Start reading from the socket.
   */
  void start();

  /**
   * Callback for socket reads.
   */
  void handle_read(const boost::system::error_code &ec,
                   size_t bytes_transferred);

  /**
   * Callback for socket writes.
   */
  void handle_write(const boost::system::error_code &ec);

  /**
   * Get a reference to the session socket.
   */
  socket_t &socket() { return socket_; }

private:
  /**
   * Session socket
   */
  socket_t socket_;

  /**
   * Buffer to be used for r/w operations.
   */
  std::array<uint8_t, 4096> buffer_;
};
```

`session.cpp`

```
#include "session.h"

#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

using boost::asio::async_write;
using boost::asio::buffer;
using boost::asio::io_service;
using boost::asio::error::connection_reset;
using boost::asio::error::eof;
using boost::system::error_code;
using boost::system::system_error;

using std::placeholders::_1;
using std::placeholders::_2;

session::session(io_service &service) : socket_{service} {}

void session::start() {
  auto handler = std::bind(&session::handle_read, shared_from_this(), _1, _2);
  socket_.async_read_some(buffer(buffer_), handler);
}

void session::handle_read(const error_code &ec, size_t bytes_transferred) {
  if (ec) {
    if (ec == eof || ec == connection_reset) {
      return;
    }

    throw system_error{ec};
  }

  std::cout << "Thread " << std::this_thread::get_id() << ": Received "
            << bytes_transferred << " bytes on " << socket_.local_endpoint()
            << " from " << socket_.remote_endpoint() << std::endl;

  auto handler = std::bind(&session::handle_write, shared_from_this(), _1);
  async_write(socket_, buffer(buffer_.data(), bytes_transferred), handler);
}

void session::handle_write(const error_code &ec) {
  if (ec) {
    throw system_error{ec};
  }

  auto handler = std::bind(&session::handle_read, shared_from_this(), _1, _2);
  socket_.async_read_some(buffer(buffer_), handler);
}
```

### Server class

The server class creates an acceptor for each given port. The acceptor will listen to the port and dispatch a socket for each incoming connection request. The waiting for an incoming connection is again implemented with a `async_`... function.

`server.h`

```
#pragma once

#include <vector>

#include <boost/asio.hpp>

#include "session.h"

/**
 * Listens to a socket and dispatches sessions for each incoming request.
 */
class server {

  using acceptor_t = boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor;
  using endpoint_t = boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint;
  using socket_t = boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket;

public:
  server(boost::asio::io_service &service, const std::vector<uint16_t> &ports);

  /**
   * Start listening for incoming requests.
   */
  void start_accept(size_t index);

  /**
   * Callback for when a request comes in.
   */
  void handle_accept(size_t index, std::shared_ptr<session> new_session,
                     const boost::system::error_code &ec);

private:

  /**
   * Reference to the I/O service that will call our callbacks.
   */
  boost::asio::io_service &service_;

  /**
   * List of acceptors each listening to (a different) socket.
   */
  std::vector<acceptor_t> acceptors_;
};
```

`server.cpp`

```
#include "server.h"

#include <functional>

#include <boost/asio.hpp>

using std::placeholders::_1;
using std::placeholders::_2;

using boost::asio::io_service;
using boost::asio::error::eof;
using boost::system::error_code;
using boost::system::system_error;

server::server(boost::asio::io_service &service,
               const std::vector<uint16_t> &ports)
    : service_{service} {

  auto create_acceptor = [&](uint16_t port) {
    acceptor_t acceptor{service};
    endpoint_t endpoint{boost::asio::ip::tcp::v4(), port};
    acceptor.open(endpoint.protocol());
    acceptor.set_option(acceptor_t::reuse_address(false));
    acceptor.bind(endpoint);
    acceptor.listen();
    return acceptor;
  };

  std::transform(ports.begin(), ports.end(), std::back_inserter(acceptors_),
                 create_acceptor);

  for (size_t i = 0; i < acceptors_.size(); i++) {
    start_accept(i);
  }
}

void server::start_accept(size_t index) {
  auto new_session{std::make_shared<session>(service_)};

  auto handler =
      std::bind(&server::handle_accept, this, index, new_session, _1);

  acceptors_[index].async_accept(new_session->socket(), handler);
}

void server::handle_accept(size_t index, std::shared_ptr<session> new_session,
                           const boost::system::error_code &ec) {
  if (ec) {
    throw system_error{ec};
  }

  new_session->start();
  start_accept(index);
}
```

### Main

The main function creates the server for a series of ports.
For this example, the ports are set to `5000`,...,`5010`. It then spawns a series of threads for each CPU core that calls the `run` function of the I/O service provided by Boost ASIO. The I/O service is capable of handling such a multi-threading scenario, dispatching work among the threads that have called its `run` function ([reference](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_context/run/overload1.html)):

> Multiple threads may call the run() function to set up a pool of threads from which the io_context may execute handlers. All threads that are waiting in the pool are equivalent and the io_context may choose any one of them to invoke a handler.

`server_main.cpp`

```
#include "server.h"

#include <numeric>

#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>

int main() {
  std::vector<uint16_t> ports{};

  // Fill ports with range [5000,5000+n)
  ports.resize(10);
  std::iota(ports.begin(), ports.end(), 5000);

  boost::asio::io_service service{};

  server s{service, ports};

  // Spawn thread group for running the I/O service
  size_t thread_count = std::min(
      static_cast<size_t>(boost::thread::hardware_concurrency()), ports.size());

  boost::thread_group tg{};
  for (size_t i = 0; i < thread_count; ++i) {
    tg.create_thread([&]() { service.run(); });
  }

  tg.join_all();

  return 0;
}
```

You could compile the server for example with `g++ -O2 -lboost_thread -lpthread {session,server,server_main}.cpp -o server`. If you run the server with clients that send it random data, you would get output such as:

```
Thread 140043413878528: Received 4096 bytes on 127.0.0.1:5007 from 127.0.0.1:40856
Thread 140043405485824: Received 4096 bytes on 127.0.0.1:5000 from 127.0.0.1:42556
Thread 140043388700416: Received 4096 bytes on 127.0.0.1:5005 from 127.0.0.1:58582
Thread 140043388700416: Received 4096 bytes on 127.0.0.1:5001 from 127.0.0.1:40192
Thread 140043388700416: Received 4096 bytes on 127.0.0.1:5003 from 127.0.0.1:42508
Thread 140043397093120: Received 4096 bytes on 127.0.0.1:5008 from 127.0.0.1:37808
Thread 140043388700416: Received 4096 bytes on 127.0.0.1:5006 from 127.0.0.1:35440
Thread 140043397093120: Received 4096 bytes on 127.0.0.1:5009 from 127.0.0.1:58306
Thread 140043405485824: Received 4096 bytes on 127.0.0.1:5002 from 127.0.0.1:56300
```

You can see the server handling multiple ports, with work being distributed among the worker threads (not necessarily restricting each thread to a specific port).